# Como logro T²-(T-1)²+(T-2)²-(T-3)²+(T-4)²-(T-5)²+...-(T-n-1)²+(T-n)²

Tags: javascript

Cómo logro desarrollar esta ecuacion? La tengo ya en (T-1)*(T-1), pero despues del bucle no se como hacer. Me da los numeros pero no se como sumarlos y restarlos a la vez. Dónde inserto la multiplicación y como hago para multiplicar con 1 y con -1?.

```js
var numP = 0;

do {
  siga1 = true;
  numP = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero positivo menor o igual a 10000: ");
  //Si no es un número menor o igual a 10000 o si es nulo o si es vacío
  if (isNaN(numP) || numP == null || numP > 10000) {
    alert("Por favor ingrese un número valido");
    siga1 = false;
  }
}
while (!siga1);

//Con el valor P dado por el usuario en el paso anterior, calcular la suma

let i = 0;
while (i < numP) {
  document.write((numP - i) * (numP - i));
  i++;
}
```

Comment: hola @joan te recomiendo que leas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask y mejores tu pregunta para asi poder asistirte

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: puedes multiplicar por 1, luego por -1, luego 1 y asi en cada iteración.

Comment: Si no incluyes el código que tienes hasta el momento, la pregunta seguramente sea cerrada en breve.

Answer (score 2):

Para cambiar el valor del signo (multiplicando por 1 o -1), esquematicamente se podría hacer asi:

```js
var numP = 0;

numP = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero positivo menor o igual a 10000: ");

if (isNaN(numP) || numP == null || numP > 10000) {
  alert("Por favor ingrese un número valido");
}

const t = numP;

const n = numP;

let es_positivo = true; // <--  con esto vemos si va 1 o -1, arranca con 1

let res = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

  let signo = (es_positivo) ? 1 : -1;

  res = res + signo * (t - i) ** 2;

  es_positivo = !es_positivo; // <--  cambiamos el true por false y viceversa en cada iteración 

}

document.write(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo mas sencillo seria implementar una funcion recursiva que te vaya cambiando el valor al que se le resta T (1,2,3...) y el valor del signo. Entonces, seria una funcion de la forma `funcion(int T, int n, int signo)` y en el cuerpo vas a tener que poner `return signo*(T-n)^2 + funcion(T, n-1, -1*signo);`
De esta manera, en cada llamado cambias el signo. Tene en cuenta que el llamado a tu funcion debe ser `funcion(T, n, signo);` donde signo=+-1 dependiendo como implementes tu codigo finalmente. O sea, no podes poner +-2 porque te cambia toda la ecuacion. Espero que te sirva.